# Not able to extract data or find problem with code

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is the code for extracting news articles for different companies from Google news. This gives me an empty excel file with only the headers. I am not able to figure out what the error is. Can someone please help out. (The entire code can be copy-pasted, and reproduced in your machine):

```
import requests
import random 
from collections import OrderedDict
def list_header():
  headers_list = [
        # Firefox 24 Linux
        {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'DNT': '1',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        },
        # Firefox Mac
        {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'DNT': '1',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        }]

  return headers_list
def list_dict():
    # Get headers list
    headers_list = list_header()
    # Create ordered dict from Headers above
    ordered_headers_list = []
    for headers in headers_list:
        h = OrderedDict()
        for header,value in headers.items():
            h[header]=value
        ordered_headers_list.append(h)
    return ordered_headers_list
def list_test():
    headers_list = list_dict()
    max = len(headers_list)
    url = 'https://httpbin.org/headers'
    for i in range(0,max):
        #Pick a random browser headers
        headers = random.choice(headers_list)
        #Create a request session
        r = requests.Session()
        r.headers = headers
        
        response = r.get(url)
        print("Request #%d\nUser-Agent Sent:%s\n\nHeaders Recevied by HTTPBin:"%(i,headers['User-Agent']))
        print(response.json())
        print("-------------------")
def random_header():
    headers_list = list_dict()
    headers = random.choice(headers_list)
    return headers
import pandas as pd
def ingest_google_news():
    ticker_list = ['AAPL.O', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', '2222.SR', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'TSLA', 'BRK-A', 'TCEHY', 'TSM', 'NVDA', 'JPM', 'BABA', 'V', 'JNJ', '005930.KS', 'WMT', 'LVMUY']

    sep = '.'
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    t_news = []
    t_publisher = []
    t_urls = []
    t_dates = []
    t_tickers = []

    for t in ticker_list:
        news = []
        publisher = []
        urls = []
        dates = []
        tickers = []

        # cleaning ticker
        ticker = t
        t = t.split(sep, 1)[0]

        # set header by random user agent 
        r = requests.Session()
        headers = random_header()
        r.headers = headers
        # print(headers)

        # set query for google
        query = '{} news'.format(t)
        url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=nws&lr=lang_en&hl=en&sort=date&num=5"
        res = r.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
        
        links = soup.select(".dbsr a")
        for l in links:
            tickers.append(t)
            try:
                url_w = l.get("href")
                print(url_w)
                urls.append(url_w)
                dt = find_date(url_w)
                dates.append(dt)

                res = requests.get(url_w, headers=headers)
                parsed_article = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
                paragraphs = parsed_article.find_all('p')

                article_text = ""
                for p in paragraphs:
                    article_text += p.text

            except Exception as e:
                article_text = ''

            news.append(article_text)

        sources = soup.select(".XTjFC g-img")
        for s in sources:
            publisher.append(s.next_sibling.lower())

        t_urls += urls
        t_news += news
        t_publisher += publisher
        t_dates += dates
        t_tickers += tickers

    df['ticker'] = t_tickers
    df['links'] = t_urls
    df['article_text'] = t_news
    df['publisher'] = t_publisher
    df['created_at'] = t_dates

    # import to csv
    today = datetime.date.today()
    d1 = today.strftime("%d%m%Y")
    df.to_csv(f'/content/drive/MyDrive/google_news_{d1}.csv')

    del news, publisher, urls, dates, tickers
    del t_news, t_publisher, t_urls, t_dates, t_tickers
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import datetime
ingest_google_news()
```

The code above is from the following link: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/google-scraping-using-beautifulsoup-d53746ef5a32

Comment: To help with an error, please post an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-News-Python-BS4-Request#bs4_result.py) (extracts the *title, link, snippet, date published, source*, and stores to `CSV`):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

ticker_list = ['AAPL.O', 'LVS', 'COTY.K','JPM', 'XOM', '005930.KS']

def get_news():

    # iterate over each ticker 
    for news in ticker_list:
        params = {
            "q": news,     # query
            "hl": "en",    # language
            "gl": "us",    # country to search from
            "tbm": "nws",  # google news filter
        }

        # store news data
        news_data = []

        html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
        
        # container with needed data
        for result in soup.select('.WlydOe'):
            title = result.select_one('.nDgy9d').text
            link = result['href']
            source = result.select_one('.CEMjEf span').text
            snippet = result.select_one('.GI74Re').text
            date_published = result.select_one('p.S1FAPd').text
            
            print(f'{title}\n{link}\n{snippet}\n{date_published}\n{source}\n')
            
            # append news data to list in dict() format to save it later via pandas
            news_data.append({
              'title': title,
              'link': link,
              'snippet': snippet,
              'date_published': date_published,
              'source': source
            })

        # create DataFrame from the list()
        df = pd.DataFrame(news_data)

        # save DataFrame to csv without default index column on the left side
        df.to_csv('bs4_final.csv', index=False)


get_news()


----------
'''
EU plans to legislate for common phone charger despite ...
https://www.reuters.com/technology/eu-plans-legislate-common-phone-charger-despite-apple-grumbles-2021-09-21/
... a person familiar with the matter said - a move likely to affect iPhone 
maker Apple (AAPL.O) more than its rivals.
2 hours ago
Reuters

Wall Street ends sharply lower in broad sell-off
https://www.reuters.com/business/wall-street-ends-sharply-lower-broad-sell-off-2021-09-20/
O), Amazon.com Inc (AMZN.O), Apple Inc (AAPL.O), Facebook Inc (FB. ... O) 
were among the biggest drags on the index as well as the S&P 500.
18 hours ago
Reuters

... other results
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google News Results API](https://serpapi.com/news-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The main difference in your example is that you don't need to make things that complicated, figure out why things just don't work as expected, and then maintain it over time. Instead, you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get what you want, fast.

Code to integrate (*same process for saving to `csv` as with code above*):

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

ticker_list = ['AAPL.O', 'LVS', 'COTY.K','JPM', 'XOM', '005930.KS']

def get_news():

    for news in ticker_list:  
        params = {
          "engine": "google",
          "q": news,
          "gl": "us",
          "tbm": "nws",
          "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),   # API environment variable
        }

        search = GoogleSearch(params)
        results = search.get_dict()

        for news_result in results["news_results"]:
          print(f"Title: {news_result['title']}\nLink: {news_result['link']}\n")


get_news()

-----------
'''
Title: EU plans to legislate for common phone charger despite ...
Link: https://www.reuters.com/technology/eu-plans-legislate-common-phone-charger-despite-apple-grumbles-2021-09-21/

Title: Wall Street ends sharply lower in broad sell-off
Link: https://www.reuters.com/business/wall-street-ends-sharply-lower-broad-sell-off-2021-09-20/

Title: S&P 500 down more than 2% as growth worries rise
Link: https://www.reuters.com/business/sp-500-down-more-than-2-growth-worries-rise-2021-09-20/

Title: Apple joins streaming elite, Netflix crosses milestone with ...
Link: https://www.reuters.com/technology/apple-joins-streaming-elite-netflix-crosses-milestone-with-emmy-wins-2021-09-20/

... other results
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.